# how to mobile responsive these divs in css without if statements in your code?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I am trying to do this in react but I don't want any if statements. I want to do this in css.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
    width: 300px;
}
.div1 {
    background-color: green;
    height: 30px;
}
.div2 {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 120px;
}
.div3 {
    background-color: pink;
    height: 60px;
}


@media all and (max-width: 400px) {
    .div1, .div2, .div3 {   
        width: 100%;
    }

}
@media all and (min-width: 401px){
    .div1 {
        width: 50%; 
        float: right;
    }
    .div2 {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
    }
    .div3 {
        width: 50%; 
        float: right;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="div1">div1</div>
    <div class="div2">div2</div>
    <div class="div3">div3</div>
</div>
```